# PHP/mySQL Data not being displayed in table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with MySQL data not being displayed via PHP
Below is the code which the data should be outputted into:

THIS IS **individual_item_page.php**

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_GET['suburb']))
    {
         $_SESSION["dog_park"] = $_GET['suburb'];
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['keyword']))
    {
         $_SESSION["dog_park"] = $_GET['keyword'];
    }
    else 
    {
        $_SESSION["dog_park"] = $_GET['rating'] ;
    }
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_SESSION["dog_park"]; ?></h1>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Park Name</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>Suburb</th>
                <th>Dog Park Area (m2)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php

            $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dog_parks.items where suburb = ?");
            $result->execute(array($_SESSION['dog_park']));
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><label><?php echo $row['Park_Name']; ?></label></td>
                <td><label><?php echo $row['Street']; ?></label></td>
                <td><label><?php echo $row['Suburb']; ?></label></td>
                <td><label><?php echo $row['Dog_Park_Area_(m2)']; ?></label></td>

            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Below is the output page after the code has been executed:
 (No data)
[image: Visual Output]

A basic overview of how the page is meant to work is,
I have 3 search types via
**keyword**
**suburb**
**rating**

If I want to search for a dog park by suburb I would select a suburb from the drop down box. (Code at bottom of page)

A table would then display the dog parks in that suburb/area which I would then click on one of those parks displayed (Hyperlinked),
which will take me to the page I am having issues with, **'individual_item_page.php'**

Below is the code for the suburb search page which then has a hyperlink to the **'individual_item_page.php'** where the issue is..

THIS IS **SUBURB SEARCH PAGE**

```
 <table class="center"> <!-- Creating a table with the class of 'center' -->

        <!-- DROP DOWN BOX -->
        <?php
        $SUBURB = $_POST['suburb'];
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT dog_park_name from items where suburb='$SUBURB'");
                $stmt->execute();
            for($i=0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); ){ 
                    $_SESSION["dog_park".$i] = $row[0];             
          ?>
         <!-- DISPLAY RESULTS -->
        <tr> <!-- Adding the first table row -->
       <th>Dog Park</th>    <!-- Adding the second table header -->
        </tr>
       <tr> <!-- Adding the second table row -->
        <td><a href="individual_item_page.php?suburb='<?php echo $row[$i] ?>' " ><?php echo $row[$i] ?></a></td>         <!-- Add the second cell on the second row -->
        </tr>
                <?php } 
                ?>  

        </table>
```

This issue has baffled me for many hours now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget to bind parameters with $stmt->bind_param() in individual_item_page.php?

Answer (score 0):

On `individual_item_page.php`, you have a couple of things going on:

1. You test for the presence of the first 2 GET variables you may be setting `$_SESSION["dog_park"]` to, but you fail to test for the third GET variable, `$_GET['rating']`.
2. Your SQL statement on that page is searching for a suburb, assuming that `$_SESSION["dog_park"]` was set to a suburb, despite the fact it may be set to `$_GET['keyword']` or `$_GET['rating']`.  Also, I'm not sure why you are binding `$_SESSION['dog park']` as an array parameter in your `$result->execute()` statement.
3. On the suburb search page you are searching the table `items` but on the individual search page you are searching `dog_parks.items`.  Was this intentional?

**Important Note:**  On your suburb search page, you use a prepared statement but manually add a user entered variable instead of binding it, which defeats the protection supplied by binding parameters, which is to **prevent** user-entered data from being directly added to SQL statements.

Comment: [3]   
Yes it was intentional as the suburb search page displays all the dog    park names from the selected suburb (Drop down box) in the items    table, which will then go to the    'individual_item_page.php'.      
Am still sorting through issues to display the correct data (New to PHP)

Comment: Have you verified that your SQL statement is returning the data you want?  You can verify this by running the statement manually in MySQL Admin.  Also, an easier way to loop through query results is: `while ($row = $result->fetch())` instead of using the `for` loop.